# How to determine whether a QML component is currently visible on screen

Tags: qt, qml

> I have a set of controls which have bindings to frequently changing data values. The data comes from a limited hardware-bus. Therefore, it would be better to disable the binding while the control is not visible on screen. The item's `visible`-property doesn't help in this case. So, how to determine if an Item-based QML widget is currently visible on screen (and not hidden by an overlay or currently outside the visible area)?

Source: https://forum.qt.io/topic/54116/how-to-check-if-a-item-is-currently-visible-on-screen

I have almost the same problem. Hoping someone here has a solution.

Comment: It sounds like you only seek for an approximation. Determining with certainty whether an item is visible.on screen is difficult! You need to take clipping and transformations into account. Approximating the problem makes it easier.

Comment: That's sensible. The right approximation might be if the system knows it *cannot* be visible, because the widget is not being drawn (as opposed to theoretically being drawn, but in reality being pre-empted by the window manager)

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I would try to get working:

First, I presume there is a ScrollView or Flickable in play here? If so, then hook to signals like Flickable::movementEnded().

Second, when that signal fires, use Item::mapToItem() to check if each of your Item's visible rectangle (based on x, y, width, height) intersects your window's contentItem rectangle. Set the result as a boolean on each of your items and make sure the data retrieval is disabled when it is false (using && or a tertiary JS expression).

Or if more convenient, remove the binding when false and reapply it with Qt.binding() when true.

Comment: I don't think this will work in this scenario. It sounds like you're describing a smart way to tell when a component has scrolled off screen, but my problem is when the embedded QML component isn't even being painted anymore because the Qt C++ interface is showing a different panel.

Comment: Seems like you have three scenarios. 1) The component is temporarily removed from the visible hierarchy 2) The component is destroyed 3) the component is off-screen. Aren't 1) and 2) easily handled by hooking the code doing the hiding/destroying and setting a boolean that accomplishes the same thing?

Comment: I don't know that it is necessarily easy or straightforward, but it is surely possible since Qt toolkit knows what to draw and what not to. What I guess I'm hoping for is some way the QML component is self-aware of whether it is visible or not. Unfortunately, the `visible` property does not track this.

Comment: I know for sure QML doesn't have that. And I don't know of any UI toolkits that have that feature either.